# vba application-defined or object-defined error (code that worked stopped working)

Tags: vba

I have a macro which worked well for a year or so.
It suddenly started giving an error and I can't understand what might have happened.

This is the code:

```
Sub CompleteData(caseDetails As CaseParam)
    Dim trackTbl As ListObject
    Dim st, ls As Integer

    
    Set trackTbl = Track.ListObjects("Tracking")
    st = caseDetails.FirstEmptyRow - 1
 
    trackTbl.ListColumns("Case ID").DataBodyRange.Offset(st).Resize(trackTbl.ListRows.Count - st) = caseDetails.caseID 'error here
    
End Sub
```

CaseParam is an object I created to hold a few variables together.

I also tried to write a test function with hard-coded values:

```
Sub CompleteData(FirstEmptyRow As integer, caseID as integer)
    Dim trackTbl As ListObject
    Dim st, ls As Integer
    
    
    Set trackTbl = Track.ListObjects("Tracking")
    st = FirstEmptyRow - 1

    trackTbl.ListColumns("Case ID").DataBodyRange.Offset(st).Resize(trackTbl.ListRows.Count - st) = caseID

End Sub
```

I also get an error, but a different one:
Object variable or With block variable not set

Again, the macro worked a long time. What could go wrong?

Updating:
I mentioned above in which line the error occurs:

```
trackTbl.ListColumns("Case ID").DataBodyRange.Offset(st).Resize(trackTbl.ListRows.Count - st) = caseID
```

Nothing changed in the code (Track sheet exists, tracking table exists). The numbers that are being passed are around 1000, so not getting close to integer limit.

caseParam lools like this:

```
Type CaseParam
    caseID As Integer
    TId As Integer
    FirstEmptyRow As Integer
    NumNewRecords As Integer
    AccountID As String
    FileC As Boolean
    TypeOfDt As String
    ReceivedOn As Date
    Incident As String
    Note As String
End Type
```

Comment: Has maybe someone changed the code name of the worksheet `Track`, renamed the table or the list column? You have declared `st` as variant (probably not relevant). Integer can be as high as `32,767` only. Hard to tell what's wrong without knowing in which line the error occurs and without the `Case Param` code.

Comment: @VBasic2008, thanks. See my answers in the update above

Comment: Has your Excel received any updates? Also worth correctly declaring st, as noted by @VBasic2008.

Comment: @RichHarding, thanks, there might have been an update. What does it mean and how does it affect my code?

Comment: @Hana, I've had VBA code broken by Excel updates in the past, so it was just a thought. I would suggest declaring both st and ls as Long (avoid overflows and mismatches) and then write a test function that just debugs st, which is the most likely source of the errors you report.